# Gibbs sampling is not producing expected results

Tags: r, random, simulation, markov-chains

I am attempting to learn the mechanics of [Gibbs sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling). I have 2 variables for which I am trying to conduct inference from. This example assumes only Gaussian distributions. My code in `R` looks like the following.

```
library(condMVNorm)

rm(list=ls())

means <- c(0, 25)
cov <- matrix(c(1.09, 1.95, 1.95, 4.52), 2, 2)

k <- 10
initSample <- c(0, 0)
traceSamples <- matrix(, k, 2)

for (i in 1:k) {
    X <- initSample[1]
    c1 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean=means, sigma=cov, dep=2, given=1, X=X)

    X <- c1
    c2 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean=means, sigma=cov, dep=1, given=2, X=X)

    currentSample <- c(c1, c2)
    traceSamples[i, ] <- currentSample
    initSample <- currentSample
}

colMeans(traceSamples)
```

What I get as the output is the following.

```
[1] 2220.7619  947.3168
```

I would have expected that the first variable would be pretty close to 25 and the second one to 0.

I do not know if my understanding is wrong with Gibbs sampling because the literature invariably says you sample from the conditional distribution `p(X1=x1|X2=x2)`. To me, `p(X1=x1|X2=x2)` is the density estimation of `X1=x1` given `X2=x2`, and one would map that to `dcmvnorm` and not `rcmvnorm`.

Printing the `traceSamples` matrix, I get the following.

```
           [,1]         [,2]
 [1,]   22.0574   -0.7827272
 [2,]   63.6865   16.3375931
 [3,]  138.7078   49.2994688
 [4,]  272.0850  107.3952335
 [5,]  510.2272  208.3522406
 [6,]  940.7504  395.4438929
 [7,] 1708.2603  725.3048137
 [8,] 3080.5096 1317.7650679
 [9,] 5538.0734 2378.8674730
[10,] 9933.2615 4275.1848015
```

The values seem to be increasing (so this suggest something is wrong with my R code). Furthermore, I also do a very simple sampling without the for loop.

```
means <- c(0, 25)
cov <- matrix(c(1.09, 1.95, 1.95, 4.52), 2, 2)
x1 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean = means, sigma = cov, dep=2, given=1, X=c(0))
x2 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean = means, sigma = cov, dep=1, given=2, X=c(x1))

x1 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean = means, sigma = cov, dep=2, given=1, X=c(x2))
x2 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean = means, sigma = cov, dep=1, given=2, X=c(x1))
```

My x1 and x2 values for each of these are as follows.

```
23.40496 -0.01044726
22.67643 -0.6836546
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Note, I was able to get better expected results with the following code.

```
means <- c(0, 25)
cov <- matrix(c(1.09, 1.95, 1.95, 4.52), 2, 2)

k <- 9000
x1 <- 0
x2 <- 0
traceSamples <- matrix(, k, 2)

for (i in 1:k) {
    x1 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean=means, sigma=cov, dep=2, given=1, X=x2)
    x2 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean=means, sigma=cov, dep=1, given=2, X=x1)

    traceSamples[i, ] <- c(x1, x2)
}

colMeans(traceSamples)
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with reusing and re-assigning `initSample`?

Comment: Do you realize that `sample(1)` will always be exactly 1? You need to start naming your variables so they don't overlap with the names of functions (eg. `sample`). I'm guessing that you meant ``sample[1]` or `sample[i]`. And `trace` and `cov` are also  R function names. Don't do that. It's not syntactically wrong, but it is semantically foolish.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Revising to `sample[1]` doesn't help though.

Comment: I offered two possibilities and suspected that it was intended to be `sample[i]` although I wasnt at all clear what that was supposed to do. Your use of comments has not been particularly liberal, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I solved the problem of why Gibbs, was providing erroneous values in the simulation, but I think it is getting complicated when doing the code in that way, I think that some lines could be removed to structure the code in a more efficient way, which is also faster. However, notice the changes I made in `x <-initSample` and `X = X[1]` and `X = X[2]`.

```
library(condMVNorm)
rm(list=ls())

means <- c(0, 25)
cov <- matrix(c(1.09, 1.95, 1.95, 4.52), 2, 2)
k <- 9000
initSample <- c(0,0)
traceSamples <- matrix(, k, 2)
for (i in 1:k){
  X <- initSample
  c1 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean=means, sigma=cov, dep=2, given=1, X=X[2])
  X <- c1
  c2 <- rcmvnorm(n=1, mean=means, sigma=cov, dep=1, given=2, X=X[1])
  currentSample <- c(c1, c2)
  traceSamples[i, ] <- currentSample
  initSample <- currentSample
}
> head(traceSamples,10)
                  [,1]                [,2]
 [1,] 23.8233821520619 -0.9169596237697860
 [2,] 22.8293033255339 -1.6287517329781345
 [3,] 21.3923155517845 -1.9104909272586084
 [4,] 20.5331401021848 -2.3320921649401360
 [5,] 21.4287399563041 -1.1376683051591154
 [6,] 23.4335659872032 -0.4379604108831421
 [7,] 25.4074041761893 -0.0613743089436460
 [8,] 24.2471298284230  0.0764901351102767
 [9,] 24.7450703427834 -1.2443499508519478
[10,] 24.2193799579308 -0.4995919725966815
> cov.wt(traceSamples)
$cov
                 [,1]             [,2]
[1,] 4.54864368811939 1.96444834328156
[2,] 1.96444834328156 1.09723665614730

$center
[1] 24.9626145462517535 -0.0163323659130855

$n.obs
[1] 9000
```

Gibbs sampler is a Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithm. Therefore you should check the convergence of the chain. The coda package provides some very useful tests.

```
library(coda)
MC <- mcmc(traceSamples)
plot(MC)
heidel.diag(MC)
Stationarity start     p-value
     test         iteration        
var1 passed       1         0.231  
var2 passed       1         0.193  

     Halfwidth Mean    Halfwidth
     test                       
var1 passed    24.9626 0.1228   
var2 failed    -0.0163 0.0598
```

[image]

Where accept the null hypothesis that the Markov chain is from a stationary distribution.

Comment: can you use `gelman.diag` for this example of gibbs sampling?